# HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout confusion

Tags: android, http, connection-timeout

I get that HttpConnectionParams used to set the timeout for an http-request, but I dont know how to use it properly. Every request has setParams(HttpParams p) - I think it's a bit redundant to set http params on each request. What I'd rather do is configure AndroidHttpClient in a global way - so that every request shares the same HttpParams configuration.

Does this `HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 1500);` operate on a global scale?